# Android repo Check out

Tags: android, repository, android-source

To check out a branch other than "master", specify it with -b:

```
$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b <froyo>
```

What should I write as '-b' option parameter for Android 3.0 HoneyComb so as to check out it from source repository ?

Comment: Google did not release HoneyComb source code and most likely will not in the near future

Comment: hmm... I didn't knew it. Quite new to this field. Just downloaded the src code for android sdk.

Comment: @Matthieu, Tim Bray pointed out that Google probably is going to release Honeycomb eventually, since it's part of the source tree and there's no resources devoted to ripping it out.  That may not be very interesting though, since it'll come out only when the next release does (Icecream?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a pretty easy answer.

[Google has not released the honeycomb source](http://phandroid.com/2011/03/24/google-withholding-honeycomb-source-from-developers-out-of-concern-for-user-experience/), so you cannot clone it. And they will probably [never release it](http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/from-io-2011-confirmed-honeycomb-source-will-never-exist-on-its-own-20110510/). However they have promised to [release the Ice Cream Sandwich source](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Google-I-O-Android-Ice-Cream-Sandwich-and-Open-Source-199736.shtml) eventually.

The [Honeycomb sources which are GPL](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-building/tzLYzYJpXOE/discussion) and can be build together with the rest of the Gingerbread release have however been released. If you do a:

```
$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b gingerbread
```

you will get Gingerbread + AOSP patches + Honeycomb sources for the GPL licensed parts of Honeycomb (which are quite few of them.)